# How to get physical address for any address in FreeBSD from userspace?

Tags: c, memory, freebsd, virtual-address-space

For some investigation, I need to find out the physical address of a pointer on FreeBSD 12.
On Linux, I would do that with `/proc/self/pagemap` but on FreeBSD, I have not found a way to do it.

So, is there a way to get the physical address of any virtual address from user-space in FreeBSD?

Comment: We are debugging some NUMA locality issues and trying to validate that the addresses are allocated on the proper CPU.

Answer (score 0):

For FreeBSD, See macro **vtop**

find(1) and xargs(1) are your friends:

```
find /usr/include /usr/src/sys -type f -name '*.h' -print0 \
| xargs -0 egrep -i vtop | less
```

I think this is a good starting point ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, vtop is a kernel macro, so I won't be able to use it from userspace. I could use it from a kernel module, but that's something I want to avoid.